# Can't install libghc-xmonad-dev and libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev

Tags: debian, apt

I use Siduction which is a rolling release Debian distro which runs off of the sid branch.

Tried to update my system and I can't seem to install  libghc-xmonad-dev and libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev.  I need this to use xmonad.  Any suggestions?

```
> apt-get install libghc-xmonad-dev libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev                                                                                                                
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                               
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                    
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                           
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have                                                                                                                           
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev : Depends: libghc-x11-dev-1.8-10997
                             Depends: libghc-x11-xft-dev-0.3.1-da3b1
 libghc-xmonad-dev : Depends: libghc-x11-dev-1.8-10997
                     Depends: libghc-data-default-dev-0.7.1.1-bf135
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the pitfalls of using a rolling release based on Sid. The Haskell packages are going through a [rebuild](https://release.debian.org/transitions/html/haskell.html), and the package tree in Sid is rather broken as a result.

You’ll have to either wait for the situation to be resolved in Sid, or use the [Buster versions](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev) which have all their dependencies available. The latter option is [explained in the Siduction manual](https://manual.siduction.org/sys-admin-apt#apt-downgrade).

Comment: Thank you.  Good advice.  I ended up installing cabal compiling xmonad independently (http://xmonad.org/intro.html).